# unable to fetch bigquery table count using airflow bq hook operator . unable to see the count or query result when trying to print the output

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Trying to run the below mentioned code **to extract the total count of a table from airflow dag** , in order to validate if the count is retrieved. I am trying to store the result in a variable and print the variable to see the result. But I am not able to see the query output when I print the variable. Looks like I am missing out on something. Is there a way to store the result into a variable.

```py
def count():
        config={
                "job_type":"Query",
                 "query":{
                          "query":"select count(*) from project_id.dataset.table",
                          "useLegacySql":False,
                          "allow_large_results":True,
                          "location":"location_name"
               }}
hook = BigQueryHook(gcp_conn_id='connect_id')
target_count=hook.insert_job(configuration=config, nowait=False)
print(target_count)
    
with models.Dag(
        'count_test',
        start_date = datetime(20, 9, 1),
        schedule_interval = None, 
        catchup = False,
        ) as dag:
    
    from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
    count_bqHook = PythonOperator(
                                   task_id='task1',
                                   python_callable=count
                                 )
    
chain( count_bqHook )
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try and consider below approach:

On your initial code, `target_count=hook.insert_job(configuration=config, nowait=False)` will store a `QueryJob` object. And per this [QueryJob](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob#google_cloud_bigquery_job_QueryJob_result) documentation, you may navigate to `result()` for you to return the actual query result and then print it in your **Cloud Composer Airflow logs**.

Below is the code I used:

```py
def count():
    config={
        "job_type":"Query",
        "query":{
            "query":"select count(*) as total_count from project_id.dataset.table",
            "useLegacySql":False,
            "allow_large_results":True,
            "location":"location_name"
        }}
    hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default', delegate_to=None, use_legacy_sql=False)
    target_count=hook.insert_job(configuration=config, project_id=PROJECT_NAME, nowait=False)
    for row in target_count.result():
        print(f'PRINTING TOTAL_COUNT --> {row.total_count}')

with models.DAG(
        'count_test',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        catchup = False,
        ) as dag:
    from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
    count_bqHook = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task1',
        python_callable=count
    )
    
    count_bqHook
```

To properly extract and print your needed value, you may refer to this [Display BQ Query Result](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#display_the_query_result) documentation.

**My Cloud Composer Airflow logs output:**

[image]

**My query executed in BQ to validate the output on Cloud Composer Airflow logs versus the actual query result in BQ:**
[image]